# Can I connect a 2nd router to a separate phone socket on same internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

We have a Virgin Media wireless router set up in the standard format. I want to boost the signal of the wifi in another room + have a cabled connection in, and in figuring a way to get an ethernet cable to that room, I found the room has a telephone port in the wall, and wondered if I can use that with a 2nd router (instead of connecting 2 routers together with ethernet).

Comment: Telephone ports don't have enough wires fir that unless they're RJ45, used in RDIS. But that isn't usually installed at home.

Comment: Is the first modem/router also connected through the phone line? Is it ADSL?

Comment: Is this device you want to use a gateway modem or a router?  If it's a modem what you plan on doing won't achieve your desired results.

Comment: @grawity Yes correct

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 1):

This can be possibly be done.but is not very practical as it requires extra pairs in your house to be connected - which is common but not guaranteed. It also requires changes to the jacks/cabling to expise one of the additional pairs, but mostly because its expensive and difficult for someone at your level. I would look into ethernet over power (eg "powerline" devices) or use WIFI or pull another cable as a more viable alternative

If it is "do or die" you can get deviced which "convert" ethernet to single pair and back - essentially how DSL is delivers Internet to msny homes, probably including yours.

Not a product recommendation +just googled it), but a pair of devices like https://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/Media-Converters/Ethernet-Extenders/vdsl2-ethernet-over-single-pair-wire-extender-kit~110VDSLEXT2 might do you.